# Excel : Find address of first and last cells with values (with blanks in between)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet which contains a large number of records that show days worked over a period of 3 years.

I essentially need to find the start and end dates for each record, using my example below I want B2 to display the contents of E2 and C2 to display I2.

[image]

Is there some way of doing this in a formula?

Comment: Is your final output going to be the date header?  Or is it really the actual address?  If it is the date header, it will be easier to get that then the address.

Comment: The date header if possible. I figured if I could get the address I should be able to work out the date headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First date:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($D2:INDEX(2:2,MATCH(1E+99,$1:$1)))/($D2:INDEX(2:2,MATCH(1E+99,$1:$1))<>""),1))
```

Second Date:

```
=INDEX($D$1:INDEX($1:$1,MATCH(1E+99,$1:$1)),MATCH(1E+99,$D2:INDEX(2:2,MATCH(1E+99,$1:$1))))
```

All entered regularly.

This will also expand to with the data automatically, no need to retype the ranges if the data table expands or shrinks in columns.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way...

```
B2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copied down:

=INDEX($D$1:$M$1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(D2:M2),0))

C2, confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copied down:

=INDEX($D$1:$M$1,MATCH(2,1/(ISNUMBER(D2:M2)),1))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I haven't tested your answer but if you explain CSE {array} formulas it would help.

Comment: After the formula is entered into the cell, instead of pressing just ENTER, you would have to press the CTRL key, and then while the CTRL key is still pressed down, you press SHIFT and ENTER.  If done correctly, Excel will automatically place curly braces {...} around the formula.